# Google Apps Script - SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl() no error but loads nothing

Tags: google-apps-script

if i use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` it works but i can't run this script with a minute-based trigger because it doesn't have an active spreadsheet.
i tried to use `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()` which runs manually inside the script editor and also runs without error from the minute-based trigger.

my problem is that no cells are updated on my actual sheet which it is supposed to output onto. i think that it's not marking the emails as read either but i receive so many constantly already that it's hard to check at the moment.

https://jsfiddle.net/29Ls3me4/1/

```
function myFunction() {

  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google*****************************/edit");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

  var threads = GmailApp.search ('label:unread "Thank you for your order!" -fwd: -re: -failure'); //search string

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var msg = messages[j].getPlainBody();
      var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
      var dat = messages[j].getDate();
      var to = messages[j].getTo();

      var dateString =
    dat.getUTCFullYear() + "/" +
    ("0" + (dat.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" +
    ("0" + dat.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);

      var name = messages[j].getSubject();
      var invoicenumber = name.match(/\d/g);

      if(invoicenumber == null){
        invoicenumber = "null";
      } else {
        invoicenumber = invoicenumber.join("");
      }

      ss.appendRow([invoicenumber, dateString, to, sub, msg])
    }
     threads[i].markRead();
     //threads[i].markUnread();
  }
}
```

Comment: just wanted to mention, the emails do update and are marked as read. so it's just the interactions regarding the spreadsheet that aren't being done and aren't giving any error either. again, all that code works fine if i just use getActiveSpreadsheet() but i need to use a timed trigger for this.

Comment: SpreadsheetApp Class is server side not client-side. Same is true about GmailApp.

Comment: i think i don't know enough, sorry in advance. i don't know why it wouldn't work then? if that class is server side then both of the functions getActiveSpreadsheet() and openByUrl() should both work or both not work? i have to be lacking on understanding the way this stuff works cuz i still don't know how to do what i need to do but it also doesn't make sense to me why one works and the other doesn't if they're both server side and not client side.

Answer (score 0):

ok simple coding eyeballs

```
ss.appendRow()
```

should've been

```
sheet.appendRow()
```